# My Java GUI Library working on windows not on Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, user-interface, platform-independent

I have a made a  Java Library to show Android like Toast messages called JSubs : [GitHub](https://github.com/Jaysmito101/jsubs)

Its working perfectly fine in my Windows 10 Computer.

[image]

But whenever I try it on Linux(Kali Linux) the system crashes and  also the message does not show properly .

[image]

My Driver code :

```
import com.jaysmito.jsubs.JSubsConstants;
import com.jaysmito.jsubs.SubsFrame;
import com.jaysmito.jsubs.Toast;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Toast.showToast("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I am not much experienced with Linux.

How can I make it computable with Linux too?

Comment: If you want good answers, I think you're going to need to give a lot more detail, as well as showing the relevant code.

Comment: @DPWork well i dont want to fill the question with code as i have given the github link just see it from there

Comment: And for details i gave as mush i felt necessary if you need more please ask

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee he already asked for more. Don't provide a github (or other) link, provide a minimal example here with which the issue can be reproduced

Comment: for example "the system crashes". How do you know that? do you get an error message? Which one?

Comment: @Stultuske the system freezes mouse doesnt responds for a moment

Comment: And what code you want its actually a library so its big so which part you want or should i give the program to import and run the library from jar

Comment: the code you wrote, the code that is causing the issue. so it just freezes for a moment? Might just be the OS working on the execution of your code. That's not necessarily a crash

Comment: @Stultuske maybe but the entire os freezes and also the message is not displayed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with accessing uninitialised values of "instance" (probably because of the threads) where in "this" would be more appropriate because that is guaranteed to be set. For example the `SubsFrame` constructor calls `handleFrameSize()` yet handleFrameSize uses "instance" -> NullPointerException.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "label" because "com.jaysmito.jsubs.SubsFrame.instance" is null
```

Swing UI changes should not be run inside different threads. Do all Swing UI operations in the main calling thread (setting up first time) or later on in Event Dispatch thread. This affects all operations inside your `new Thread(new Runnable ...)` calls, use  `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);` for the bits that change the UI in those background threads.

I could run your app on Linux once fixed above and commented out:

```
 //    if(!this.isAlwaysOnTopSupported()){
 //        throw new Exception("Always on top is not supported!");
 //    }
```